# Add health check to Kafka consumer k8s pods

Tags: python, django, apache-kafka, kafka-python, health-check

How to add health check`(liveness/readiness)` in Kafka consumer pods in my Django application. New to this infra-structure related things. Please help in implementing a periodic health check for Kafka consumer pods in my application so that it does not allow pods to rotate if their health is not perfect if there is any issue.

Comment: We were using a custom health check for `livenss/readiness` probes. Similar to this: https://github.com/devshawn/kafka-connect-healthcheck#get-ping

Comment: where is this port 18083 coming from?

Comment: https://github.com/devshawn/kafka-connect-healthcheck/blob/master/kafka_connect_healthcheck/parser.py#L26, default port for this health check server. You can override it using `HEALTHCHECK_PORT`

Answer (score 1):

You could add a simple `GET /health` endpoint that returns a 200 status.

Or if you want something more dynamic to what the Kafka consumer is doing, catch exceptions in your consumer and flip a boolean variable that is inspected as part of your `/health` route to return `500` code upon any severe error. Kubernetes then will terminate any pods with non-200 HTTP status probe

Comment: but this is for health check, if we add catch block in consumer that will coz different issues, will it not get triggered for other reasons too?

Comment: How do you define a healthy consumer? If there is a processing exception, it is not healthy, IMO. You can subclass different types of exceptions for what is considered a fatal event or not. If there are no messages to consume, the consumer is idle, sure, but the k8s pod itself is still healthy

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ask yourself two questions:

- Q1: If Kafka does not work, how many APIs or features of your application can continue to work? In another word, how important is Kafka to your application?
- Q2: If Kafka does not work, can it be solved by a restart of the container?

If the answer of Q1 is "some" or "many", then you don't need to do anything in your readiness probe. Unless the answer of Q1 is "very few" or "none", then you should report 500 in your readiness probe.

If the answer of Q2 is "yes", then you can report 500 in your liveness probe, otherwise just report 200 OK.

The reason behind them can be found here: https://danielw.cn/health-check-probes-in-k8s